# Boolean boxing in Java 1.3

Tags: java, boxing

For some reason I have to maintain a Java 1.3 project. I use some Boolean but it seems that to give them default values I have to box them like this

`Boolean disableAllTheThings = new Boolean(false);`

Is there a way to have this automatically with a constant somewhere such as

`Boolean disableAllTheThings = FALSE_CONSTANT;`

It is not that important it just feels weird to box Booleans.

Comment: how about `Boolean.FALSE`  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no boxing in your example, but you create an unnecessary object. How about using the [constant provided by the Boolean class (link to 1.3 API)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#FALSE) instead:

```
Boolean disableAllThings = Boolean.FALSE;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [`Boolean.FALSE` (and `Boolean.TRUE`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).  They were around since the beginning of Java, and they certainly were there in Java 1.3.1.